# Can I use Maven with Sencha Cmd instead of Ant, or must it use Ant?

Tags: maven, extjs, ant, sencha-cmd

We are making changes to use Sencha Cmd, but it uses Ant. We use Maven for other things, so can we make changes to a config file or something, so Sencha Cmd uses Maven not Ant, or must we have Ant installed to use Sencha Cmd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

You can build your Sencha ExtJS project with Maven using Sencha CMD. It's rather easy.
Check my example project Sencha ExtJS 5 + Sencha Cmd 5 + Maven:

https://github.com/dobromyslov/sencha-extjs-maven

[Sencha ExtJS 5.0 BETA available](http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-public-beta-of-ext-js-5/) at the moment.
Read [Sencha CMD docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/getting_started/getting_started.html) and try it in action.

Then just put your project in the `webapp` folder and use `exec-maven-plugin` to build your ExtJS application with Sencha CMD like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>sencha-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Set path to your Sencha Cmd executable-->
            <executable>../Sencha/Cmd/5.0.0.116/sencha</executable>
            <arguments>
                <argument>-sdk</argument>
                <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</argument>
                <argument>app</argument>
                <argument>build</argument>
                <argument>--clean</argument>
                <argument>--environment</argument>
                <argument>${sencha.env}</argument>
                <argument>--destination</argument>
                <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/build</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

If you want to purge unnecessary files from the resulting WAR file then use `maven-war-plugin` with configured exclusions like this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<configuration>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <webResources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/webapp/build/${sencha.env}/MyApp</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/Readme.md</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </webResources>
    <packagingExcludes>.sencha/**,app/**,build/**,ext/**,overrides/**,packages/**,sass/**,bootstrap.css,bootstrap.js,bootstrap.json,build.xml,Readme.md</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

> We use Maven for other things, so can we make changes to a config file or something, so  >  Sencha Cmd uses Maven not Ant

No. Sencha Cmd is built on Ant.

> must we have Ant installed to use Sencha Cmd

No. Sencha Cmd is delivered with an ant version it is used.

*How to use it with maven?* The simplest way is to use installed Sencha Cmd with [Maven Antrun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).
Take a look at my comment [Simple use of Sencha Cmd and Maven Antrun plugin](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?268087-Calling-Sencha-CMD-in-Maven-compile-Cannot-find-com-sencha-ant-antlib.xml&p=1029277&viewfull=1#post1029277).
Further reading about [Sencha Cmd and Ant integration](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/command_ant).

Answer (score 1):

Sencha Cmd ships with the Ant version that works with it. You don't need to install Ant separately.